# About positions a Rectangle on the screen

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I have a `JFrame` and a class extending `JPanel` and overriding `paintComponent()` (named `DrawingPanel`). An instance of `DrawingPanel` is added to the `JFrame`.

This is the `paintComponent()` method of `DrawingPanel`:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(80,180,50,50);
    g2d.fill(rect);
}
```

I ran the program, and it seems that the coordinats 80, 180 specified when creating `rect`, refer to the `JFrame` that contains the instance of `DrawingPanel`. I would expect that these coordinates would refer to the `JPanel` where the rectangle is actually painted.

1) Is it supposed to be like that?

2) Is it possible to change this?

Thanks

Comment: I suspect that the pane is sitting with a BorderLayout on the frame, which makes the pane will the viewable area of the frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would expect that these coordinates would refer to the JPanel where the rectangle is actually painted.

They do refer to the JPanel, not the frame.

Why do you think they refer to the frame? Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.